# Execute an instance of Matlab using C# for all versions

Tags: c#, matlab, com

I wrote a small C# program that creates a Matlab instance and launches a .m script.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MATLAB_APP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
            matlab.Execute("cd('"+ System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MLab\\Optimization')");
            matlab.Execute("Main");
        }
    }
}
```

The program runs only on the computer used in the compilation. If i run it on a different computer, i get an error on a console. (Yes the files are in the exact directory they are supposed to be). Is there anything i can do in order to make this program usable on other computers (with different windows/Matlab versions) ?

Comment: What is the error?